Should I include my counterespionage-type of research in my resume as a programmer?
I've been a back-end developer for the past 4 years with quite a few info-sec related contributions in my department.
In my personal time, I research various espionage/hacking techniques used by intelligence agencies with the goal to determine what’s possible, inform the public and to develop effective counter-measures.
So far I've published a new attack against an extremely popular anonymity tool. It was well perceived by the tool devs and people reading my resume.
So let's say my laser-microphone-type of research was published (not exactly what I researched).
Should I include it in my resume?
I've been advised by a friend who works as a manager that how I  phrase it is critical:

This is amazing. But if I sense that you could cause me trouble in the future, I wouldn't hire you.

Is his opinion correct and if so, how should I phase it?

To give a bit more context:

I've proven a type of spying is possible by state-actors
these techniques are definitely known by state-actors (but not advertised)
it can be used for industrial espionage as well, but other techniques are more dominant
the research will protect journalists, activists, etc. from having their secrets exposed
it cannot be used by ordinary criminals (requires sophisticated tools and know-how)
it is not code related; but proves my very strong analytical skills


For what kind of jobs/industries are you applying? Are those infosec related?

You should include ANYTHING on your resume/cv that would be relevant to the position you're applying for. If you're applying for a cybersecurity analyst position, this sounds like a great add-on. If you're applying to marketing lead generation position, it doesn't sound terribly useful. In any case, include anything that tells them more about you as a worker/person/value add to the organization.

Does this give you an answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/197378/should-i-mention-in-my-resume-i-have-written-exploit-code-thats-incorporated-int/197489#197489

@DarkCygnus most aren't, but some are.

Could someone explain why the question was downvoted and closed as "opinion-based"? How should I improve it? I see 9 Related questions to the side, but I have a hard time understanding how to make my question more like them.

@TheDemonLord very interesting read, thank you. I guess the answers there answer my question as well. The only difference is my project can be seen as much more controversial-"scary".

"Counterespionage type of research" would scare me off unless I was looking for those specific skills; it sounds like the person may be delusional unless their were doing things for a government agency (in which case they would probably be forbidden to talk about it). Saying you have experience as a white hat hacker, and being specific about which tooling you are familiar with, would be less troubling but is still a rather specialized skill set.

@keshlam "delusional" - that's a critical point I've missed. To me "turning power-supplies into speakers to leak data" from air-gapped and sound-gapped systems is absolutely normal, scientific research; a cold fact. To HR it's movie plot. And the protagonist's motives are evil on first sight. Thanks. Explains a lot.

Exactly. It's legitimate, but for most non-government applications it's massive overkill and a focus on the wrong thing -- secure windows are irrelevant if you leave the door open. And your choice of terminology (counterespionage") emphasizes that, as well as sounding a bit too eager to try it... If you want to use these skills as part of your marketing, sell it as your knowing everything from basic hardening through network security through security design and review of code, and if it comes up in the interview you can say "and even some of the extreme stuff like..."

Be very careful that you don't come across as a risk to them.  Caring about the security of software you write is a good thing.
But they really don't want one of their employees being caught hacking into their competitors, a government agency, or even the sensitive sections of their own computers that hold personal or confidential data.  You may have the best motives, but for them, there's a huge reputational risk.

Good point. I do follow all laws and regulations tbh, I've even studied them quite a bit just to make sure everything I do is legal. Hacking and spying for nefarious purposes can result in multi-decade long sentence, but recruiters might not know/think about it. Somewhat irrelevant... do you think it's a bad idea to mention in to current colleagues?


So far I've published a new attack against an extremely popular anonymity tool. It was well perceived by the tool devs and people reading my resume (including my managers).

I'm confused as to why you would ever have current managers reading your resume.
Aside from that very confusing bit, I'd say that if you're distributing your resume for positions that don't have anything to do with information security, you run the potential of spooking the HR people and having your resume end up in the trash before it ever has a chance of getting to a hiring manager's desk.  Run-of-the-mill situations often claim they want the best and brightest, UNTIL they run into someone like you.
I had a consulting gig once where I had to supply my own laptop.  The base operating system was Ubuntu, and I had Windows executing in a VM.  The work itself required Windows.  In this environment, any device plugged into their network had to be approved to have its MAC address added to a whitelist for Wi-fi access, and when these people found out I had a Linux machine, they flipped out.  No one could quote a specific risk, but this scenario created just too many unknowns for the IT director.  In the end, they had to get me another machine running Windows directly.

Apologies for the confusion. I meant to say, they too perceived it well. They didn't read my updated resume. I'll edit it out if that's ok.

I'm curious about the info-sec part. My guess is bigger companies have more "specific"  roles, so they don't care as much about tangentially related achievements? Is my understanding correct? Also, for positions that are related to security, any tips on how to phrase it? (and especially what to avoid) Not getting them spooked is my biggest concern.

@Antony I'm chuckling here.  I'm assuming your core role isn't the info sec contributions you've mentioned.  Those contributions are valuable, yes-indeed.  SUMMARIZE them into a single bullet point on your resume.  Do NOT mention your personal research on your resume.  Don't do it!  If an interviewer wants to ask more about your info sec work contributions, share some of that in the interview.  If they're highly interested in those info sec contributions, you might share more after you start the job but if not, I suggest keep your mouth shut.  Don't endanger getting your foot in the door

Thank you for your advice so far. One last question if I may. So no DefCon talks I guess?

Without clarification from the OP, I'd've assumed he worked in a contracting/consulting role; and has an internal resume used by business development people on proposals.  I had one at a prior job.
